# Mulit-part download from S3 bucket with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-s3, multipart, aws-sdk-js

I want to do a multi-part download from S3 for large files (1 Gb+) using Angular. There is a lack of documentation and I haven't found a single example which explains this in detail.

Enough documentation available for multi-part upload.

I am using `s3.getObject()` method from [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk).

I know that we can get a chunk by passing the `Range` parameter to `s3.getObject()`. I need help on how to pass these range for large files, how to maintain the chunks and how to combine all of them at last.

Let's say I have the user authenticated and I wish to download a large file from private S3 bucket in multi-part for faster downloads. Any help is appreciated.